# IText7 only creates form/widgets on new documents

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

When running this code with the PdfDocument not having a read source, it works properly. When I try reading from a premade pdf it stops creating the form/widgets, but still adds the paragraph as expected. There is no error given. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Here is the code I'm running:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static final String DEST = "sampleOutput.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "sample.pdf";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);

        new HelloWorld().createPdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
        //Initialize PDF reader and writer
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer); //if i do (reader, writer) the widget isn't added to the first page anymore.

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        HelloWorld.addAcroForm(pdf, document);

        //Close document
        document.close();
    }

    public static PdfAcroForm addAcroForm(PdfDocument pdf, Document doc) throws IOException {
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Test Form")
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setFontSize(16);
        doc.add(title);
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Full name:").setFontSize(12));

        //Add acroform
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc.getPdfDocument(), true);
        //Create text field
        PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfFormField.createText(doc.getPdfDocument(),
                new Rectangle(99, 753, 425, 15), "name", "");

        form.addField(nameField);
        return form;

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: thank you for providing example code. It's so much easier to answer a question when people give us a sample that we can compile to test. I have tried your example and I couldn't reproduce the problem: the field is added correctly when I try your code. I am using iText 7.0.1 and a source file with page size A4. Could we take a look at your source file. Maybe the page size is defined differently. If the origin of your coordinate system (`(0, 0)`) isn't in the lower-left corner, you could get the problem you describe.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for the response. Here is the sample file, see anything that would throw this off? http://www.filedropper.com/sample_15

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Great idea with the origin. I played around with the x and y coordinates and I think I was just putting the widget out of range. Much appreciated! Look forward to using the tool more.

Comment: The X and Y coordinate are indeed an issue: your page is 612 user units hight, but you add the field at y = 753. There is a second problem: the field is added on page 7, and you probably want to add it to page 1. Apart from the Jump-Start tutorial examples, I haven't written that many form examples for iText 7, I'll see if I can find what to do to add the field on page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your code like this:

```
public static PdfAcroForm addAcroForm(PdfDocument pdf, Document doc) throws IOException {
    Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Test Form")
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .setFontSize(16);
    doc.add(title);
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Full name:").setFontSize(12));

    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
    PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf,
            new Rectangle(99, 525, 425, 15), "name", "");
    form.addField(nameField, pdf.getPage(1));
    return form;
}
```

You'll notice two changes:

1. I change the Y offset of the field (`525` instead of `753`). Now the field is added inside the visible area of the page. In your code, the field was added, but it wasn't visible.
2. I defined to which page the fields needs to be added by adding `pdf.getPage(1)` as second parameter for the `addField()` method.

Comment: This is the solution, thank you. I have 1 other problem I will be submitting and would appreciate your knowledge. I am unable to use two widgets referencing the same form value. I only see both widgets when I change the form values to be separate.